# R - milestone chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a project milestone chart in ggplot2 which consists of several layers involving a bar to show the distance between activities, points to show the activities name and a shape to show the start date of activities. Below is an image for example.

The distance in the bar is calculated based on the ***DayDiff*** field in data which is the difference in days between start date and end date.

[image: Milestone Chart - Distance in bar is calculated based on day difference]

***Sample Data***

```
df <- structure(list(End = c("5/1/1990", "2/16/1991", "8/31/1991", 
      "12/31/1992"), Start = c("1/1/1990", "6/1/1990", "2/17/1991", 
      "9/1/1991"), Activity = c("First Activity", "Lean period", "Holidays", 
      "Final Phase")), .Names = c("End", "Start", "Activity"), class = 
      "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df$DayDiff <-  as.numeric(as.Date(df$End, format='%m/%d/%Y') - 
               as.Date(df$Start, format='%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Is this chart possible in ggplot2? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try to use the DayDiff Column you have created but just created a new column for start date as follows. I did this to show and make sure the x-axis values used are of Date values. Also I thought there is no use to do the DayDiff since all activities start date is just the next day after end of the previous one.

```
df$DateS_new <- as.Date(df$Start, format = format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then played around ggplot geoms to create your figure. Below is the code used to produce the figure shown below

```
ggplot(df, aes(DateS_new,y=(rep(0.3,4)))) + geom_rect(aes(ymin=0.302, ymax=0.298, xmin=as.Date("1989-11-01"),xmax=as.Date("1991-11-01"))) + geom_point(shape=21,size=10,fill="red") + geom_point(aes(DateS_new,y=rep(0.28,4)),shape=25,size=3) + annotate("text", x=df$DateS_new, y=0.32, label=df$Activity) + scale_x_date(name=NULL,breaks=df$DateS_new, date_labels = "%d-%m-%Y") + theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(name = NULL) + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[Click here for the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4ydp.png)

Hope this is helpful.